# Vertical progress bar in xaml and vb.net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, progress-bar

Need help on creating a vertical progress bar in my application.

Haven't started the app so no current code to work off,

Just planning to see if this is possible, any input would be great,

*p.s. if the progress bar could either progress upwards or downwards would be very helpful*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ProgressBar ...>
  <ProgressBar.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90"/>
  </ProgressBar.LayoutTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

Rotate by -90 to make it go the other direction

Comment: Doesn't it support [Orientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.orientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property out the box with both Vertical/Horizontal templates built into the style already? Not sure a Transform is necessary.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes it does, good one! But that doesn't make it possible to select up/down fill direction

Comment: yes that is the problem I was occurring, but @ErnodeWeerd that solution worked perfectly for me, thanks